# How can i set date and time with my version in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to attach current date and time with the version in pom.xml . Can anyone give me the best way to do it.

Comment: I would take a deep look into [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [maven-timestamp-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-timestamp-plugin/) or buildnumber-maven-plugin.